# Background music get louder each time a scene is loaded

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `GameObject` on level01 with an `Audio Source` and the `script` below.
When the game starts the script runs and music starts playing.

The problem I have is that each time I load a new level the sound gets louder. I don't understand why this is happening. Can someone explain why and give a solution or point me in the right direction?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MusicManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip[] songs;
    int currentSong = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (audio.isPlaying == false) {
            currentSong = currentSong % songs.Length;
            audio.clip = songs[currentSong];
            audio.Play();
            currentSong++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you instantiate another object with this script attached when a scene is loaded? Since you don't destroy it, you probably end up with more than one audio source playing the same clip.

Comment: If I allow it to be destroyed the music stops once another level loads.

Comment: I've just tried it and it doesn't get louder for me. Another guess: try putting your script (and AudioSource) on the main camera (or anything that has AudioListener component)

Comment: Ah! I forgot to turn off 3D sound on the audio clip and the camera on the game over level was closer to the sound manager so it played louder. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I see that your answer was that your camera was simply closer to the 3D audio source, but I've put my answer here anyway as it is a common solution to a common problem.

You're instantiating your music manager every time you enter a scene with your music manager in it, but you're never destroying a music manager, which duplicates the sound. What you need is a singleton - a way of telling your code never to allow multiple instances. Try this:

```
public class MusicManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static MusicManagerScript instance = null;

    public AudioClip[] songs;
    int currentSong = 0;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(this);
            return;
        }
        instance = this;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (audio.isPlaying == false)
        {
            currentSong = currentSong % songs.Length;
            audio.clip = songs[currentSong];
            audio.Play();
            currentSong++;
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        //If you destroy the singleton elsewhere, reset the instance to null, 
        //but don't reset it every time you destroy any instance of MusicManagerScript 
        //because then the singleton pattern won't work (because the Singleton code in 
        //Awake destroys it too)
        if (instance == this)
        {
            instance = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Because instance is static, every music manager script will have access to it. If it's been set already, they destroy themselves when they're created.